# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackRuntimeLibrariesForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding, android-databinding

My project was working fine, I stopped development for a week and when I came back, when I build the project I get this exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackRuntimeLibrariesForDebug'. > com.android.sched.scheduler.RunnerProcessException: Error during 'ReachingDefinitions' runner on 'static void org.mozilla.universalchardet.prober.contextanalysis.JapaneseContextAnalysis.
```

I tried to change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`, it was actually 1536.
No change.

What is this exception about? How to fix it?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I was planning to use Data Binding in this project. Apparently,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

and this

```
classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'
```

caused his behaviour.
The question is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to enable `DataBinding` in `build.gradle` to use it

```
android{
    defaultConfig{
        dataBinding {
            enabled true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I must have missed it in the video tutorial I was watching)